# "regardless of your belief" vs "regardless of what you believe in"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I wonder if these two phrases are the same in terms of meaning:

"regardless of your belief" and "regardless of what you believe in"

> **Regardless of your belief**, you have heard or asked this question or questions like this and of course you have not reached a conclusion!
>
> **Regardless of what you believe in**, you have heard or asked this question or questions like this and of course you have not reached a conclusion!

By the way, does the following sounds normal?

> "regardless of your any kind of belief"

Comment: That last one sounds awkward and in need of revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Regardless of your belief*" would normally be used to refer to a specific opnion or thought, a particular belief as in:

> - Regardless of your belief that it leaves at 2, the train actually departs at 3 pm.
> - Regardless of your belief that you know how to operate the machine, you must be certified in its use.

"*Regardless of what you believe **in***" would be used to refer to a **system** of belief, such as a religion or a philosophy.

> - Regardless of what you believe in, you must respect the religious views of others.
> - Regardless of what you believe in, not everyone is a Green Party member.

Comment: Yeah, it's not so much about ***belief / believe*** - it's the preposition ***in***. In which context, there's the difference between *I believe you* (I think you are speaking the truth) and *I believe **in** you* (I have confidence in you).

Comment: Another way we might allude to a system of belief is to use "beliefs" (in the plural): _Regardless of your beliefs, you must respect the religious views of others._